# Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog - It is but not found I guess

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been getting this error for about a month now and cannot get past it no matter what I try. I have tried putting all the images in there for iPhone and iPad as well as the app icon. I have tried changing the app icon to a different image from the rest. I have tried using the asset catalog with Assets and also with Media and nothing is working. Here is how Assets look.

[image]

As you can see all are filled up and the 1024X1024 app icon is in place. Again I have also tried using Media and here is how that looks,

[image]

I have played a lot with my info.plist but that has not helped either. I cannot get past this. In reading all the posts on the internet, there is none of them that I have not tried far as I know so your help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Have you added this key `XSAppIconAssets ` to your Info.plist file? Try to add the moved the pair back to the top of the file. Fore more details, you can go through this [similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/578798/missing-app-icon-when-uploading-to-transporter.html).

Comment: I am afraid that did not work, same results. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I found a [similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/578798/missing-app-icon-when-uploading-to-transporter.html) on `Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels`. You can go through it.

Comment: Still no luck. Neither of those worked for me nor anything else I have tried. My code that works has the appicons under a Media asset catalog, so I even tried that but no luck. Do you have to have the images in a specific directory to be brought and found? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what I did, I could not get past this. I finally pulled from a pretty old checkin from before this all started and now I no longer have the issue. Sorry I can't give good news with a solution, but like I said, nothing worked, and I tried a ton of things.

Comment: I am stuck with the exact same problem. I am at the point of just creating a new project and copying everything over :(